# Восстановить ярлыки с рабочего стола

Tags: windows, файлы, windows-10, восстановление

Случайно удалил (а точнее, переименовал в один файл) пачку ярлыков с рабочего стола. Recuva удалённые файлы не нашла. Как можно восстановить ярлыки или хотя бы узнать их имена? Восстановление системы включена, последняя контрольная точка 4 дня назад, но использовать откат системы я не хочу. К тому же, часть из них была создана после этой даты.

Насколько я представлю, Windows отслеживает изменения по ярлыкам и где-то нужная информация хранится? Правда, ошибочное переименование было сделано из bash, что может несколько усложнить ситуацию.

Comment: На сколько я знаю - история ярлыков нигде специально не хранится. Так что скорее всего - болты.

Comment: Файлы .lnk ничем принципиально не отличаются от любых других файлов, и система операции с ними не отслеживает (вот зачем бы ей это было вообще нужно?).

Comment: @freim, вроде при использовании восстановления системы ярлыки тоже откатываются, значит они должны быть частью точки восстановления, т. е. они где-то хранятся, как и исполняемые файлы. Разве не так?

Comment: Может это поможет https://www.nicbedford.co.uk/software/systemrestoreexplorer

Comment: При восстановлении возможно, да и то скорее всего не специально ярлыки,  а содержимое папок Desktop и StartMenu. А обычные файловые операции с ними не отслеживаются, разумеется.

Comment: @PavelGridin, о, вроде есть что-то, хотя и не во всех точках.

Comment: Если ярлыки ссылались на исполнимые файлы, можно попытаться восстановить ссылки по истории исполняемых файлов. В ветке реестра **RecentApps**, может в каталоге **prefetch** и т.д.